# Hybrid App WP7: Ad not visible, but clickable

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, ads

I followed the documentation from Microsoft to include Microsoft ads in my hybrid Game. Everything works fine, but the "test-ad" is not visible! But if I tap the position where it should be, it opens up bing. Here my Draw:

```
private void OnDraw(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
    {
        SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        background.Draw(spriteBatch);

        // Draw the Enemies
        for (int i = 0; i < Plattforms.Count; i++)
        {
            Plattforms[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
        }


        powerbar.DrawPower(spriteBatch);
        player.Draw(spriteBatch);
        particleComponent.Draw(spriteBatch);
        particleComponentfinal.Draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, level.score.ToString(), new Vector2(20, 20), Color.White);

        if (bg.donebook == true) { spriteBatch.Draw(bg.done, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White); }

        if (countdown == true) { spriteBatch.DrawString(countfont, countdowntime.ToString(), new Vector2(360, 200), Color.White); }

        // draw the ad control
        AdComponent.Current.Draw();

        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you following all the steps in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873087%28v=msads.20%29.aspx) guide, including setting up the correct rectangles (80x480 reserved for the ad control) and hooking up the Update and Render methods? The behavior you describe seems that the layout system expects to have the ad control in the right place but your framebuffer doesn't contain it's visual data.

Comment: Yes, I followed exactly this guide, and my rectangle is 480x80 as it should be.

Comment: AdComponent.Initialize("test_client");
            
            Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle rect = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(0, 0, 480, 80);
            drawableAd = AdComponent.Current.CreateAd("Image480_80", rect, true);
            
            drawableAd.AdRefreshed += new EventHandler(drawableAd_AdRefreshed);
            drawableAd.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Advertising.AdErrorEventArgs>(drawableAd_ErrorOccurred);

My initialize code.

Comment: is this a landscape orientated ad?

Comment: If you can repro this with a simple example - I would recommend sharing it so we can try it out for ourselves.